# Solving a Ratio Problem with Three Variables

Tags: ratio

A question that just popped in my head after reading an article:

> If the radius of Planet X is 16% larger than that of Earth, and Planet X has 40% the radius of Planet Y, then what is the radius of Planet Y in terms of Earth radii?

I'm having trouble trying to figure this one out. How would we solve this one?

I understand we may have to define one variable in terms of another to get the desired result, but again, I seem to be failing miserably at it.

Comment: I literally just realized that and removed it. You beat me to it!

Comment: Also, I have since reworded the problem accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

We have $X = 1.16E$ and $X= 0.4Y$.

Equating these we get $1.16E = 0.4 Y \implies Y = \frac{1.16}{0.4}E = 2.9E$.

So the radius of planet $Y$ is $2.9$ Earth radii.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$, $Y$ and $E$ be the radii of the two planets and Earth, respectively.  Then

$X = 1.16E$

and

$X = 1.40Y$

Substitution gives you $1.16E = 1.40Y$

Solve that equation for $Y$ and you'll have the result that you're looking for.

Comment: x is 16% *larger*, not 16% of total.

Comment: It was my mistake. G. Allen based this answer on the problem before I made an edit to it. Apologies.

Comment: Easy enough to fix.  I edited my post to reflect the new wording.

Comment: Shouldn't that be X = 0.4Y?